# Macports duplicate packages

Tags: python, macos, macports, homebrew

I have already Python 2.7 on my Mac Os 10.7 and i tried to install py27-mysql package that contains MySQLdb interface for Python. I had run `sudo ports install py27-mysql` and macports began to install all dependencies for that package python2.7, mysql5, etc that I already has.

Now the questions:

1. Why that happens?
2. Where is now native Mac Os python and mysql?
3. Which one I use after installation if I work from command shell?
4. Is brew better?

Comment: No `brew` is not better. It's more ambiguous, but can save you disk space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macports installs the packages in /opt/local/ and /opt/local/bin.

You can always find your default OS package installation in /bin and /usr/bin.

OS default python installation: /usr/bin/python

Of course, you can choose the macports by having /opt/local/bin first in your path. Macport installation works very well for me.